# Checkbox check is not using passed in value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react checkbox and I set the value of the checkbox based on a useEffect. The checkbox is showing as always checked rather than unchecked if the value is false.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (recent && !(recent instanceof RequestError)) {
      recent.answers.forEach((ans) => {
         const foundQuestion = questions.find((q) => q.id === ans.questionId)
         if (foundQuestion && !values[foundQuestion.id]) {
            setFieldValue(foundQuestion.id, ans.answer)
         }
      })
   }
}, [recent, questions, values])
```

that is the use effect that sets the values
below is the code being called on the onclick event of the checkbox

```
const handleAnswersCheckbox = (q: Question): ((evt: 
ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => void) => {
   return () => {
      setFieldValue(q.id, (values as Record<string, string>)[q.id])
   }
}
```

the q.id is the correct id for the value which is false but the checkbox is checked all the time.

this works for all the other controls except the checkbox